# How can I mix hot and cold water in a dual flow tap?

Tags: faucet

We have an old kitchen dual flow tap. This tap has 2 holes, from were the hot and cold water come from. So the hot and cold water do not mix, this means that we end up burning and freezing our hands at the same time.

[image]
[image]

I've heard this type of tap is for when there's some issue with pressure, but on the bathroom we have a modern tap that mixes the hot and cold water.

Is there a way to mix the cold and hot water without having to replace the tap?
Maybe putting something at the end of the tap?

Comment: Think the best idea is a replacement, there does not like any place at the end to add something that would look neat.  Maybe clamp a short piece of hose over it.  That or try to cut out some of the centre piece so the water can mix inside.  Both are not good ideas, more of last choice.